# SQL server silent install with weak password

Tags: sql-server

For the setup of an application i wanted to do a silent install of sql server. For backward compatibility the server needs a weak sa password.
I know that sa should not be used and i know that it should not have a weak password, but I'm not responsible for this and I can't change this part.

When trying to do a silent install with SAPWD="ThePassword" i get an error, that the password does not match the password policies. Is there any way to force the weak password in silent installation?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

As score already pointed out, you need to change the security policies to do this. If there would be a way to install something that breaks a company policy without disabling the said policy, that would be technically a 'vulnerability' and the operation would be called an 'exploit'.

Now you have two options:

- change the company policy to allow the application.
- obey the company policies and don't allow the application.

Is really simple as this...

Comment: That's sounds logical, but then why can you disable password policy enforcement per-user after installation? (see "enforce password policy" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189425.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup SQL unattendly whith some realy strong pass (yes it depends on M$)
2. sqlcmd  -S. -E -Q "ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD=N'some_weak_pass', CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF"

that's all. login or use it whith weak pass. tested on 2008 r2

P.S. also you can install unattendly using integrated security mode and later use sqlcmd to switch sql server into combine mode to use SA with weak pass

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

- Run secpol.msc on the server before installation.
- Go to account policies -> password policy

[image: Go to account policies - password policy]

- Disable "Password must meet complexity requirements" and give it another go

Comment: I wanted a silent install(It's included in an installer). Therefore a user interaction is not possible. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: I thought it would be ok to set this option before running the installer. Maybe you can set this option by using `secedit` (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/secedit_cmds.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken, but I don't believe the SA account, or any other SQL (non-Windows) accounts respect this policy.

Comment: The password policy is global and respected by SQL Server. See also http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1088 and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2009/03/25/enforce-password-policy-on-sql-server-logins.aspx